# How to publish to the same AWS IoT Thing topic from multiple endpoints?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I'm currently running a test on an IoT project which is utilizing AWS IOT Core service. I have an MQTT broker with a Thing set up to which I have connection policies defined and authentication access certificates generated. Using these with a policy defined ClientID, I'm able to successfully publish project's sensors data(i.e temperature, humidity, soil pH and ambient light values) to the MQTT broker using Raspberry pi pico(RP2040) microcontroller device.
From the broker, I've set up DynamoDB database tables to which the received data at the broker level is consumed. Then using NodeJs APIs listener, the data is fetched for display in a NodeJs web application in realtime. All these so far works well.

However, my actual problem kicks in whenever I try to publish data(set threshold values) from the platform to the MQTT broker using the very same topic to which the RP2040 device is publishing. Immediately whenever the platform published data is received at the broker, device published data stops being received by the broker.

Here's the API for handling platform publishing of DHT sensor threshold:

```
// -----------Publish to broker---------------
// DHT sensor component threshold
router.get('/dht-threshold-mqtt-publish', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("\nData Publishing ---------------------------");
  try {
    const { project_id, user_id } = req.query;

    // Fetch data from MongoDB based on project_id and user_id
    const dhtSensorData = await DHTSensor.findOne({ project_id, user_id });

    if (!dhtSensorData) {// validate if data isa available
      return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'DHTSensor data not found' });
    }

    // Extract the temp_threshold from the retrieved data
    const tempThreshold = dhtSensorData.temp_threshold.toString();
    const humidThreshold = dhtSensorData.humid_threshold.toString();

    console.log("Component: DHT\nPublished thresholds;\n -Temperature: "+tempThreshold+"\n -Humidity: "+humidThreshold);

    // Construct the JSON payload
    const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({
      user_id: user_id.toString(),
      project_id: project_id.toString(),
      dht_temperature_threshold: tempThreshold,
      dht_humidity_threshold: humidThreshold,
    });

    // call MQTT setup
    await mqttDataPublishHandler(jsonPayload, 'DHTSensor', res);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

And the publishing function handler:

```
// MQTT broker data publish handler
async function mqttDataPublishHandler(dataPayload, targetComponent, res) {
  const mqttBrokerUrl = process.env.MQTT_BROKER_URL; // MQTT broker URL
  const topic = process.env.MQTT_PUB_TOPIC;
  const clientId = process.env.MQTT_CLIENT_ID; // Set your unique client_id
  console.log("MQTT broker url: ", mqttBrokerUrl);

  const mqttOptions = {
    clientId: clientId,
    protocol: 'mqtts', // Use 'mqtts' for MQTT over TLS/SSL
    rejectUnauthorized: true, // Set to "false" to ignore certificate validation (for testing only)
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.MQTT_CLIENT_KEY_PATH), // Set path to your client key
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.MQTT_CLIENT_CERT_PATH), // Set path to your client certificate
    ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.MQTT_CA_CERT_PATH), // Set path to your CA certificate
  };

  const mqttClient = mqtt.connect(mqttBrokerUrl, mqttOptions);

  let responseSent = false;

  mqttClient.on('error', (err) => {
    if (!responseSent) {
      console.error('MQTT Connection Error:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'MQTT Connection Error' });
      responseSent = true;
    }
  });

  mqttClient.on('connect', () => {
    // Publish payload to the specified MQTT topic
    mqttClient.publish(topic, dataPayload.toString(), (err) => {
      if (!responseSent) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('MQTT Publish Error:', err);
          res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'MQTT Publish Error' });
        } else {
          console.log(targetComponent+" threshold data published to MQTT broker.");
          // Close the MQTT connection
          mqttClient.end();
          // Respond to the client
          res.json({ success: true, data: dataPayload });
        }
        responseSent = true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Does this mean AWS IoT ***thing*** can't support multi-device publishing to a common topic  and so I should consider creating a topic under **Many Things**?

At initial stage of experiencing this, I thought it could be due to creation of concurrent connections to MQTT broker from different endpoints(platform API and from device firmware). I resolved this by ensuring platform connection to broker is only initiated at the time a new sensor threshold value is being set and thereafter close the connection.
However, this did not resolve the issue.`

Any assistance kindly in case you've come across this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after some research around the internet and from different forums with total regards to aws [re:Post](https://repost.aws/) I managed to get a solution around this task.

Using same certificates for the two things provisioned(although I'll consider to use independent certificate for each as recommended), I successfully managed to publish to the same AWS IoT Thing topic (`device_dht22/pub`) from multiple endpoints i.e RP2040 device and the platform supported with nodejs.

First, I had the main AWS IoT thing, `DEVICE_DHT22` with clientID as `DEVICE_DHT22` and pub/sub topics as `device_dht22/pub` and `device_dht22/sub` respectively. The device publish sensor data to broker via `device_dht22/pub.`

```
//DEVICE_DHT22 thing policy ---------------------------------------------------
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:XXXXXX:client/DEVICE_DHT22"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:XXXXXX:topic/device_dht22/pub"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:XXXXXX:topicfilter/device_dht22/sub"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:XXXXXX:topic/device_dht22/sub"
    }
  ]
}
// END ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On the other hand, the platform is to publish control threshold settings back to the connected device via the broker through d`evice_dht22/sub`, the topic to which the device is listening to ( subscribed to ) for the set thresholds.

The second AWS IoT thing is `PLATFORM_DHT` with clientID as `PLATFORM_DHT` and pub/sub topics as `device_dht22/sub` for publish topic and the subscribe topic as `platform_dht/sub`.

```
//PLATFORM_DHT thing policy ---------------------------------------------------
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:XXXXXX:client/PLATFORM_DHT"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:XXXXXX:topic/device_dht22/sub"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:XXXXXX:topicfilter/platform_dht/sub"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:XXXXXX:topic/platform_dht/sub"
    }
  ]
}
// END ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These two AWS IoT things sharing same `certificate` and having different `client IDs` from their policy settings made it possible to initiate simultaneous exchange of data between the device and the platform backend database endpoints via the MQTT broker of a single AWS IoT thing  `DEVICE_DHT22`.

Special regards to [@Giovanni](https://repost.aws/community/users/USjmPEnk9rTOSU7Ss5hZMPVA) and [@Gavin_A](https://repost.aws/community/users/US3_psKfF4ROqmqbPbvjmZ0A) on [re:Post](https://repost.aws/) for their positively insightful responses that guided me in working on this.

You can get more from their responses [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUR9sfNGhyRpyg46lrJy4OvQ/how-to-publish-to-the-same-aws-iot-thing-topic-from-multiple-endpoints#AN5NHnw5B1SCqy5TIKD8E_kg) and [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUR9sfNGhyRpyg46lrJy4OvQ/how-to-publish-to-the-same-aws-iot-thing-topic-from-multiple-endpoints#AN3jN2uXjxTF6s8WBuF5KDjw).

Thank you all!